# Jenkins plugin repo fails to build in ci.jenkins.io but builds locally

Tags: maven, machine-learning, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-antrun-plugin

The failed pipeline logs says:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:3.1.0:run (createTempDir) on project machine-learning: You are using 'tasks' which has been removed from the maven-antrun-plugin. Please use 'target' and refer to the >>Major Version Upgrade to version 3.0.0<< on the plugin site.

Here is my pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  ~ The MIT License

  ~ Copyright 2020 Loghi Perinpanayagam.

  ~ Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
  ~ of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
  ~ in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
  ~ to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
  ~ copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
  ~ furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

  ~ The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
  ~ all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

  ~ THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
  ~ IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
  ~ FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
  ~ AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
  ~ LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
  ~ OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
  ~ THE SOFTWARE.
-->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.50</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.jenkins.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>machine-learning</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>hpi</packaging>
    <properties>
        <jenkins.version>2.204.1</jenkins.version>
        <java.level>8</java.level>
        <no-test-jar>false</no-test-jar>
        <useBeta>true</useBeta>
        <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
        <configuration-as-code.version>1.36</configuration-as-code.version>
        <slf4jVersion>1.7.26</slf4jVersion>
        <spotbugs.effort>Max</spotbugs.effort>
        <spotbugs.failOnError>true</spotbugs.failOnError>
        <spotbugs.threshold>Medium</spotbugs.threshold>
        <zeppelin.version>0.9.0-preview1</zeppelin.version>
    </properties>
    <name>Machine Learning Plugin</name>
    <description>A Jenkins plugin that helps to ease Machine Learning workflow. </description>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>MIT License</name>
            <url>https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jenkins.tools.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom-2.204.x</artifactId>
                <version>10</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>structs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
            <artifactId>jenkins-core</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jline</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jline</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-cps</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-job</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-basic-steps</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-durable-task-step</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.zeppelin</groupId>
            <artifactId>zeppelin-interpreter</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0-preview1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId> org.sonatype.sisu</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sisu-guice</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.zeppelin/zeppelin-python -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.zeppelin</groupId>
            <artifactId>zeppelin-python</artifactId>
            <version>${zeppelin.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.31</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.activation</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.inject/jersey-hk2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudbees-folder</artifactId>
            <version>6.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.zeppelin</groupId>
            <artifactId>zeppelin-jupyter</artifactId>
            <version>${zeppelin.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>29.0-jre</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>checker-qual</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.plugins/docker-workflow -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-workflow</artifactId>
            <version>1.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.plugins/command-launcher -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>command-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>git</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <developers>
      <developer>
        <id>loghijiaha</id>
        <name>Perinpanayagam Loghi</name>
        <email>loghijiaha@gmail.com</email>
      </developer>
    </developers>

    <url>https://github.com/jenkinsci/${project.artifactId}-plugin</url>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/jenkinsci/${project.artifactId}-plugin.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:jenkinsci/${project.artifactId}-plugin.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/jenkinsci/${project.artifactId}-plugin</url>
      <tag>1.0</tag>
  </scm>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-hpi-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalOptions>-Xdoclint:none</additionalOptions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.rat</groupId>
                <artifactId>apache-rat-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>src/</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>src/test/resources/*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the version

```html
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.3</version>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Is this an *answer* or what?